# What is the difference between `use` and `pub use`?

Tags: rust

there is something I don't understand in Rust's documentation: it's the `pub` keyword in front of `use`, what does it do?
Here is the example from Rust's documentation ([Here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-04-bringing-paths-into-scope-with-the-use-keyword.html)):

```c
mod front_of_house {
    pub mod hosting {
        pub fn add_to_waitlist() {
            println!("Added to waitlist");
        }
    }
}

pub use crate::front_of_house::hosting;

pub fn eat_at_restaurant() {
    hosting::add_to_waitlist();
    hosting::add_to_waitlist();
    hosting::add_to_waitlist();
}
```

when I try to make a main to interact with this I came up with:

```c
use tests::eat_at_restaurant;

fn main() {
    eat_at_restaurant();
}
```

but when I remove the `use` keyword it does the same thing and I can't in any case call `hosting::add_to_waitlist` from main, so what happens here ? what is the difference if I don't put the `pub` keyword ?

Comment: Did you read the [section on that page about `pub use`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-04-bringing-paths-into-scope-with-the-use-keyword.html#re-exporting-names-with-pub-use)?

Comment: Also, if your module is in a [different file](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-05-separating-modules-into-different-files.html), you have to declare it with `mod module_name` in order to be able to use it.

Comment: @Herohtar yes but I didn't understand this part

Comment: `use x::y::name` means "make the referenced item available in the current module's namespace". But that doesn't make `name` _public_ -  you can refer to `name` inside the current module, but users of your module cannot access `your_module::name`. `pub use` also makes it publically available, so that `your_module::name` works. Since `pub use` imports an identifier and immediately exports it, it's also called a _re-export_. Hope this helps.

Comment: @user4815162342 so what does it change here ? when I write `hosting::addtowaitlist()` without `pub use` it works too, so my question is in which case it won't work? what does it mean "users of your module cannot access `your_module::name`"?

Comment: "`If we hadn’t specified pub use, the eat_at_restaurant function could call hosting::add_to_waitlist in its scope, but external code couldn’t take advantage of this new path.`" The part I don't understand, because when I try to call `hosting::add_to_waitlist` from main, even with `use front_of_house::hosting`, the compiler won't let me do it because the module `front_of_house` is private, so anyway external code can't interact with it

Comment: The fact that ``front_of_house`` is private is a *completely different problem*. ``pub use`` makes the referenced item available to external code. If the referenced item is private, of *course* the compiler is going to complain. If you make the referenced item public, however, it will work as expected.

Comment: User of the module is outside code who tries to use its public API. `pub use` vs `use` doesn't make a difference for that module, it makes a difference for the users of that module (`pub use` makes the name publicly available).

Comment: With `pub use`, you can call `tests::hosting::add_to_waitlist` from `main` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c8ac41b51def972be7ac7a41983cdbe9)). With plain `use`, you would need to call `tests::front_of_house::hosting::add_to_waitlist`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`use` is used to import an item into the current module,
`pub use` allows us to (not only import but,) re-export the item.

Here's an example where `pub use` is required:

```rust
// src/foo/mod.rs

mod bar;
pub use bar::item;
```

```rust
// src/foo/bar.rs

pub fn item() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

```rust
// src/main.rs

mod foo;
use foo::item;

fn main() {
    item();
}
```

If we had used a plain `use` then `item` wouldn't be accessible. However, since we added the `pub` keyword, `item` is now available to all modules that use the `nested` module.

We call this "re-exporting" because `item` isn't actually defined in `foo` but rather `foo` "re-exports" `item` from `foo::bar`.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand a bit better now, but does it mean that the exemple they use is a bad example ? `pub use` is not needed in it, that;s why I didn't understand quite well

Comment: Their example is a little cryptic to be honest. It does explain it correctly, however they aren't really showing *where* one would use `pub use`.